# PnP Js - reading headers from request

Tags: spfx, pnpjs, batch, header

I'm using PnPJs v3 for getting a data with REST API from SharePoint Online. Because there are many request, I'd like to implement a logic to avoid throttling.

I can't figure out how to **read (any) headers** from any response (200 - OK, 429 - Too Many request) - using TypeScript.

I tried to add every parser mention on PnPJs documentation - https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/queryable/behaviors/#headerparse for single request and batch request.

```
// simplified code
import { JSONParse, DefaultParse, HeaderParse, JSONHeaderParse, InjectHeaders } from "@pnp/queryable";
 sp = spfi().using(SPFx(context), InjectHeaders({
      "X-Application": "My-App",
    }), DefaultParse(), HeaderParse());
return sp
```

e.g. `JSONHeaderParse` returns values `data` and `header` but header property is empty.

```
let items:any = null;
try {
   items = await getSP().web.lists.getByTitle("MyList").items.getById(1)();
} catch(err) {
   // or with "MyNonExistingList"
   if(err?.isHttpRequestError) {
      console.log("---err", err);
      // console.log(err.headers.get("Retry-After"));
   }
}
```

My questions:

- how to read headers for OK together with data and
- how to read headers for Error case

*Thanks.*

Answer (score 0):

Answer for **Error case**:

in catch block:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (err) {
   console.log("---My requested header:", err.response.headers.get("x-cache"));
}
```

You don't even need to provide any parser.

---

When you go to class `HttpRequestError` which extend `Error`

```
export declare class HttpRequestError extends Error {
    response: Response;
    status: number;
    statusText: string;
    isHttpRequestError: boolean;
    constructor(message: string, response: Response, status?: number, statusText?: string);
    static init(r: Response): Promise<HttpRequestError>;
}
```

and continue in `response`

```
interface Response extends Body {
    readonly headers: Headers;
    readonly ok: boolean;
    readonly redirected: boolean;
    readonly status: number;
    readonly statusText: string;
    readonly type: ResponseType;
    readonly url: string;
    clone(): Response;
}
```

You can find header there .